# Xcode 9 Swift 4 - Reposition views by dragging

Tags: ios, xcode, swift4, gesture

Im quite new to iOS development. But have years of programming experience.
Anyway, Im having a hard time finding a solution for my problem.

In my app i render rows of colored circles based on data from the server.
Each of these circles has different properties set to them on the server.
One of these is the "offset" property.
This should be used to render the circle with a distance from its left sibling, or the start of the parent view if its the first.

Each circle should then also be able to be moved by dragging it to the right or left. But never less then 0 from its left sibling.

In android this was very easy, just set the left-margin on drag, and all was good.

But in xcode im having a very hard time figuring out how to get this done.

Im sure its me thats way to inexperienced. So I hope someone that has a bit more knowledge about swift can help me with this.

Heres some images to make clear what Im looking to achive.

[First render where one circle has an offset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tZyNp.jpg)

[image]

[The gesture where the 3. last circle is drages to the right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JyPOF.jpg)

[image]

[The result of the gesture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JSMwX.jpg)

[image]

I need this to move seamless, so not reposiotioning after the gesture ends, but move along with the finger.
As you can see, the circles right of the one that is drages, keep their relative position to the one that is moved.

Thank you.

Comment: Btw, the offset unit is based on the width of a circle.
So offset: 1 means a left-offset of the same width as one circle, offset: 0.5 means a left-offset of half the width of a circle.

Answer (score 0):

There are couples of ways to do this.The First possible solution can be using the Swipe gestures to move the objects.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let swipeGesture = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "handleSwipe:")
    swipeGesture.direction = [.Down, .Up]
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeGesture)
}

func handleSwipe(sender: UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {
    print(sender.direction)
}
```

Use these Gestures to move along the objects with your fingers either you can use `.left` and `.right` gestures depending upon your need.

> The Second solution for drag components can be a Pan Gesture

```
func detectPan(recognizer:UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
  var translation  = recognizer.translationInView(self.superview!)
  self.center = CGPointMake(lastLocation.x + translation.x, lastLocation.y + translation.y)
}
```

The translation variable detects the new coordinates of the view when panning. The center of the view will be adjusted according to the changed coordinates.

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
  // Promote the touched view
  self.superview?.bringSubviewToFront(self)

  // Remember original location
  lastLocation = self.center
}
```

When the view is clicked, the current view will be displayed in front of the other views and the center of the view will be assigned to the lastlocation variable

Hope this helps.